# incompatibility between cURL and python request

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests

I have the following curl command that is meant to interface with a tplink url (to turn on a smart plug) and works as expected:

```
curl  --request POST "https://wap.tplinkcloud.com/?token=[token] HTTP/1.1" \
--data '{"method":"passthrough", "params": {"deviceId": "[deviceid]", "requestData": "{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":1}}}" }}' \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

The example above performs as expected (My tplink smartplug turns on). When trying to translate to python request, I am using this:

```
url = "https://wap.tplinkcloud.com?token=[token]  HTTP/1.1"

data = "{\"method\":\"passthrough\", \"params\": {\"deviceId\": \"[deviceid]\", \"requestData\": \"{\\\"system\\\":{\\\"set_relay_state\\\":{\\\"state\\\":1}}}\" }}"

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print r.text
```

My output is:

```
{"error_code":-20651,"msg":"Token expired"}
```

Both requests are using the same token and device ID.

I have used httpbin.org on both requests, and this is the comparison I am seeing:

cURL:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"method\":\"passthrough\", \"params\": {\"deviceId\": \"[deviceid]\", \"requestData\": \"{\\\"system\\\":{\\\"set_relay_state\\\":{\\\"state\\\":1}}}\" }}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "160", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.54.0"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "method": "passthrough", 
    "params": {
      "deviceId": "[deviceid]", 
      "requestData": "{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":1}}}"
    }
  }, 
  "origin": "[myip]", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Python:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "{\"method\":\"passthrough\", \"params\": {\"deviceId\": \"[deviceid]\", \"requestData\": \"{\\\"system\\\":{\\\"set_relay_state\\\":{\\\"state\\\":1}}}\" }}", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {}, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "Content-Length": "160", 
    "Content-Type": "application/json", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.18.4"
  }, 
  "json": {
    "method": "passthrough", 
    "params": {
      "deviceId": "[deviceid]", 
      "requestData": "{\"system\":{\"set_relay_state\":{\"state\":1}}}"
    }
  }, 
  "origin": "[myip]", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong? Maybe I'm having header issues?

Comment: "https://wap.tplinkcloud.com?token=[token]  HTTP/1.1" is not a URL

Comment: true, just used that because it worked from the curl example. But it makes no difference removing it.

Comment: Well the "Token expired" message is pretty unambiguous, I don't think it's a problem with the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something obvious.

```
url = "https://wap.tplinkcloud.com?token=[token]  HTTP/1.1"
```

is not a proper URL. That `HTTP/1.1` will be interpreted as part of the token.

In general I dis-recommend using JSON string literals. Use the corresponding data structures and convert to JSON at the point of data transfer, i.e. right before making an HTTP request or writing to file or database. At the very least this makes sure that structural mistakes, which would otherwise be opaque in the string, become compiler errors.

The same goes for the URL parameters, the proper encoding will be handled transparently by the `requests` module.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://wap.tplinkcloud.com"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept-Charset": "UTF-8"}
params = {"token": "[token]"}

request_data = {"system": {"set_relay_state":{"state":1}}}
data = {
    "method": "passthrough",
    "params": {
        "deviceId": "[deviceid]",
        "requestData": json.dumps(request_data)
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, params=params, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print response.text
```

Comment: awesome, getting this error though: `TypeError: post() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data'`

Comment: Meh, it's necessary to make `params` a kwarg in `requests.post()`. I've corrected the code.

Comment: That did it. Thank you!

Comment: Now that you have something that works, reduce it to a non-working state to learn what difference it was that triggers the error.